# How to increment versionCode using APKTool?

Tags: android, reverse-engineering, apktool

I need to increment `versionCode` in signed APK file.

I do following:

1. `apktool d myapk.apk`
2. open `apktool.yml`, increment `versionCode` and save
3. `apktool b`
4. `jarsigner` and `zipalign`

Apk works well on a phone, but `versionCode` has not been changed.
Here's `apktool.yml`:

```
version: 2.0.0
apkFileName: iVet.apk
isFrameworkApk: false
usesFramework:
  ids:
  - 1
sdkInfo:
  minSdkVersion: '16'
  targetSdkVersion: '21'
packageInfo:
  forced-package-id: '127'
versionInfo:
  versionCode: '3'
  versionName: '1.1'
compressionType: false
sharedLibrary: false
unknownFiles:
  VERSION: '8'
```

Comment: Did you try modifying AndroidManifest.xml instead?

Comment: @Michael nope, AndroidManifest contains strange value named platformBuildVersionCode which value isn't "2" which I need to increment

Answer (score 5):

**Warning:** What you are doing will invalidate the signature. You'll have to resign it afterwards to install it, and it won't look like the original dev made it. There's no way around this, except exploits.

You can just put the `versionCode` in `AndroidManifest.xml` and it will override the arguments given to `aapt` from `apktool.yml` with a warning. I just confirmed this myself.

Example changes to `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:installLocation="internalOnly" package="com.example.someApp" android:versionCode="12345" android:versionName="1.2.3.4.5">
```

Setting version information: https://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/versioning.html#appversioning

What the `aapt` command would look like if you changed `apktool.yml`:

```
Aug 11, 2015 12:56:52 PM brut.androlib.res.AndrolibResources aaptPackage
INFO: [/var/folders/5m/jph9d7q573b5yl5ybnhhx4000000gn/T/brut_util_Jar_5616282982200298928.tmp, p, -v, --forced-package-id, 127, --min-sdk-version, 5, --version-code, 12345, --version-name, 1.2.3.4.5, -F, /Users/caleb/example/someApp.apk, -0, arsc, -A, /Users/caleb/example/./assets, /Users/caleb/example/./build/apk]
```

It's clear the values in `apktool.yml` are pulled from `AndroidManifest.xml`:
https://github.com/iBotPeaches/Apktool/blob/0370416d9029d01f210556ab3662e3fa0f80c239/brut.apktool/apktool-lib/src/main/java/brut/androlib/res/decoder/XmlPullStreamDecoder.java#L96

For some reason they're not included in the decoded `<manifest>` attribute. This could be a bug.